# Can a low side L-spike destroy a turned off microcontroller through its ground pin?

Tags: inductor, servo, flyback, rtc, spike

I am working on a low power project involving servo motors and an STM32 Bluepill MCU board and I was wondering if it was necessary to place a free-wheeling diode as  shown in the schematic below (D1).

The 5V supply is actually a switching regulator that is enabled or disabled through an SR-latch's signal (the buck converter comes with an integrated Enable pin, it is substituted by the NPN "EN" in the sch.), this signal  also enables Q1, and in turn, drives Q2 (Motor and Board switch). Whenever Q (SR latch output) is high, the regulator is enabled. As for when it is low , the user has the option to manually turn on the buck converter using the toggle push button SW1. (This converter is meant to be used as a phone charger or as a 5V output.)

The purpose of this design is to greatly reduce the quiescent current of the regulator; the SR latch is powered through VBAT. The STM32 periodically(every 10 seconds) goes into VBAT mode (Q2 OFF) until the Alarm output on PC13 sets the latch which repeats this whole cycle. The reason behind this explanation is so you can understand that the MCU will be turned off during the L-spike (powered through VBAT => Only Backup registers are on). With that being said, will the L-spikes (Q2 off) cause any issues I might have overlooked in this circuit?

Extra specs:
SR latch: Made using HEF4011BP Quad nand.

Motors: (in Parallel, shown as an inductor in sch)

- 1 x SG90 microservo.
- 1 x SM-S4303R 360° continuous rotation servo.

Regulator: LM2596T-12.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkN0a4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Connecting noisy load like DC motor is and sensitive device like uC on the same source can couse a trouble. Supply the MCU thru series diode and place the own cap after should help. Flyback diode on DC motor is a must. A small cap parallel to winding is also good (many times underestimated).

Comment: @MichalPodmanický why is a flyback diode necessary here, can you please explain what it would protect exactly?
also "Supply the MCU thru series diode and place the own cap after should help" do you mean adding a parallel cap to the mcu and a diode in series with it right?
"A small cap parallel to winding is also good " - parallel to the motors right?

Comment: The commutator of motors switches the winding few times for every turn what couses the back EMF from windings (a negative voltage across). This energy must be disipated (in diode) rather then to flow to path you dont want to.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický BEMF is positive.

Comment: I mean like schematic below. The MCU has the own cap so Vcc pin is not affected (too much) by inductor spikes and ripple in power supply. Maybe the diode is already in STM32 board as part of reverse polarity (I dont know). The disadvantage in your case is the MCU will be supplied from C1 some time after Mosfet disconnection so choose the capacity according your needs. [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkAWx.png)

Comment: @jay Are you sure? I didn't mean back EMF of motor.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický "Switching commutation" does not generate EMF either. If a DC linear motor has to generate positive and negative voltage while spinning, it should be AC motor.

Comment: @jay putting aside brush contact noise, the motor does produce a reverse emf(voltage drop) when spinning regardless of whether it is an AC or DC motor , isn't that right? if not then could you please elaborate on what you've said above ?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I willdefinetly take your advice above!

Comment: @A.H.Z I don't think there is anything like "reverse emf". Either AC or DC EMF is EMF, no reverse EMF.  [Back-EMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter-electromotive_force) is not "reverse". BTW, an inductor may not represent a motor. The diode may protect the circuitry when the motor spins backward.